# simulate transaction error

Tags: spl-token, python, raydium, jupiter, simulate

trying to simulate a swap transaction

using jupiter for the quote + serialized swap tx

the error im getting is:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': {'context': {'apiVersion': '1.17.21', 'slot': 250049932},
  'value': {'accounts': None,
   'err': 'AccountNotFound',
   'logs': [],
   'returnData': None,
   'unitsConsumed': 0}},
 'id': 1}
```

code:

```
import requests
import json
from solders.keypair import Keypair


solana_rpc = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com'

def get_new_wallet():
    keypair = Keypair()
    wallet = keypair.pubkey()
    secret = keypair.secret()
    return wallet

def get_percent_token_supply(token):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    json_data = {
        'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        'id': 1,
        'method': 'getTokenSupply',
        'params': [
            token
        ],
    }

    response = requests.post(url=solana_rpc, json=json_data, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    amount = data.get('result').get('value').get('amount')
    current_supply = data.get('result').get('value').get('uiAmount')
    point_one_percent_supply = current_supply * 0.001
    return point_one_percent_supply

def get_jup_quote(input_mint: str = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112", output_mint: str = "EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v", amount: int = 0) -> dict:
    """
    required params:
    inputMint = Input token mint address: str
    outputMint = Output token mint address: str
    amount = token amount: int
    """
    jup_quote_url = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote'
    params = {
        'inputMint': input_mint,
        'outputMint': output_mint,
        'amount': amount
    }
    response = requests.get(url=jup_quote_url, params=params)
    return response.json()

def get_serialized_tx(user_public_key: str, quote_response: dict, wrap_and_unwrap_sol: bool = True) -> dict:
    """
    required params:
    userPublicKey = The user public key: str
    quoteResponse = The object that is returned from the Quote API: quote response
    """
    jup_swap_url = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    if not isinstance(user_public_key, str):
        user_public_key = str(user_public_key)
    data = {
        "quoteResponse": quote_response,
        "userPublicKey": user_public_key,
        "wrapAndUnwrapSol": wrap_and_unwrap_sol
    }
    response = requests.post(url=jup_swap_url, headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()

def simulate_transaction(tx):
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "simulateTransaction",
        "params": [
            tx,
            {
                "encoding":"base64",
                "replaceRecentBlockhash": True
            }
        ]
    }

    response = requests.post(url=solana_rpc, headers=headers, json=data)
    return response.json()


token_mint_address = '2adFTbyzVwMwPtgV68DUnrfdwB6tTAJiiVxJ6D8nwiEG'
wallet = get_new_wallet()
quote = get_jup_quote(
    output_mint=token_mint_address,
    amount=int(get_percent_token_supply(token=token_mint_address))
)
serialized_tx = get_serialized_tx(
    user_public_key=wallet,
    quote_response=quote
)
swap_transaction = serialized_tx.get('swapTransaction')
test = simulate_transaction(tx=swap_transaction)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The error says "AccountNotFound", so one of the accounts provided, likely an associated token account of the new wallet you've created, doesn't exist. Be sure that your "new wallet" has token accounts for the source and destination token type.